# Data from MYSQL Database straight to Input fields, depending on what is written in first input field

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

looking for guidance/assistance on PHP, MYSQL, HTML, Previously in all the code I've been given I'm very hack and slashy, and as long as it works that's great, and if a problem arises, I deal with it as they appear.

I have a form - http://jsfiddle.net/Yrdit/yQzsh/ - on an internal project. I have 1 database that contains numerous tables, but only 2 *Should* matter for what I need.

In my Form I have already figured out how to populate from 1 table the username and password.

In the two tables, there is 1 column that I want to be linked. - In Table 1 it is called company_name in table 2 it is called - user_company.

Table 1 handles the companies phone number, address etc.

Table 2 handles the username / password / name.

In my Fiddle I want Phone/ Address/ City/ Zip/ Country field's to be filled in depending on what is in the Company one.

Say if in my table my company is called CompanyABC, and has its details completed in the database Table 1. I want those values put into the fields I listed above.

```
$Table_1 = $db->get_row("SELECT user_login,user_password,user_name,user_email FROM Table_1 WHERE (user_id = $url_user_id) limit 1;");
```

Above is the part of code used as a request to get the login/ name/ password. Can anyone in a similar format guide me through how I can do what I've spoken about above please?

Apologies in advance if the formatting is wrong, I read the rules but might've missed something about formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but I'm assuming you wish to pull company info from table 1 and user info from table 2. If so you can use join - assuming you have some sort of identifier field in between the two... I.e. company_id. company names could work but this would not be good approach. 1. company names can be misspelled / uper-lower case issues / indexing performance. For the example sake lets join two tables on company name.

```
"SELECT t1.user_login,t1.user_password,t1.user_name,t1.user_email FROM Table_1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2 ON t2.user_company = t1.company_name WHERE t1.user_id = $url_user_id LIMIT 1"
```

Hopefully that is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Alright I'll have a play about with that and see if I can get it working Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Was playing around with this, and couldn't resolve an issue of #1054 - Unknown column '$url_user_id' in 'where clause'

I was trying to run it through the PHPMyAdmin SQL as a query, I presume that's why its erroring as there is nothing for it to relate to compared to if it was in my PHP document? Also, I've changed the table names to Table1 and Table2 so they have no spaces any more. 

One last question, in your example t1, t2, I presume you've just abbreviated the table names here?

Comment: Make sure you are passing sql through doublequotes and not single quotes "SQL QUERY" also wrap $url_user_id in like this "SQL QUERY WHERE user_id = '{$url_user_id}'".  This is in case the var is passed as string. Which you should avoid doing as this can lead to SQL injection. Yes the t1. t2 are just abbreviations but using shorthand by omitting AS instead of Table1 AS t1 you can write Table1 t1

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look when I get back at my PC, which will be tomorrow now. I'll keep you updated.